# Is it a problem when sending email where the 'from address' has multiple emails?

Tags: java, email

I am sending emails using javax mail APIs in a batch process. Due to an error in configuration the 'from' address got set to multiple comma separated email addresses.

The code snippet is like the following:

```
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage (mailSession);
...
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
```

I did not get exceptions but I am not sure if the emails were sent correctly; and if they were sent whether they would end up in recipient's spam.

Is it valid to send emails using java APIs where 'from' email address has multiple values?

Comment: And what exactly is your question here?

Comment: I was trying to find if multiple 'from' email address is valid when sending emails using java APIs

Comment: Is there something preventing you from trying it and seeing what happens? [SMTP seems to support it](https://serverfault.com/questions/554520/smtp-allows-for-multiple-from-addresses-in-the-rfc-was-this-ever-useful-why-do)

Comment: It sounds like the concept itself [should be supported](https://serverfault.com/q/554520), though it's certainly a use case I've *never* seen or used.  If you have to rely on it, test it to make sure it works.  Though it sounds like using this in your system was the result of a bug that should be corrected anyway, so this could be a moot point entirely.

Comment: I do not see any exceptions.  I was trying to find out if multiple 'from' email address could cause a problem with the email server sending the email or at the recipient's end.  I can perhaps write code to verify what happens.

Comment: @David It is eventually a bug that is to be corrected but this is deployed to production environment.  I was just trying to find out if this could cause a problem.

Comment: @user2125853 "*I was trying to find out if multiple 'from' email address could cause a problem with the email server*" Without knowing the precise vendor and version, no one can answer this. Yours might be non-compliant with the spec.

Comment: You are correct the email does not go if the 'from' has multiple email addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor `InternetAddress(String)` should throw an exception, if parsing the given string does not precisely return a single, valid email-address. So, I'll assume that your given "from" parameter is parsed into a single e-mail-address which is wrong in any case.

According to [RFC822](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc822#section-4.4), the FROM field of an email must only contain a single "identity"

Comment: You are correct the mail will not go if the 'from' has multiple email addresses.